# Do Stripe webhooks work for refunds issued via the Stripe website?

Tags: stripe, refund, webhook

Webhooks are working fine for Stripe payments.    Refunds issued for events that were cancelled are showing an error on the Stripe account.   Should refunds issue calls to Civi for the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Refunding from the Stripe side has worked for some time.